# get generated php output data in html generated file

Tags: php, html

I have a php file that has data coming from the database called **Casino-review.php**
I just want to copy the php generated output data from this file to a new html file. I have tried lots of other thinks like **OB functions, File contents functions, Copy functions, Fopen functions** but, nothing work for me. Everthing is working properly creating file copying content but it's showing php code in it. Please help me.

here is the [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UITJV.jpg).

here is my code

```
            $fileName = $title.".html";
            $to = "casinos/all/".$fileName;
            $from = "casinos/casino-review.php";
            $newcontent = file_get_contents("$from");
            if ($createFile = fopen($to, "w+")) {
                fread($createFile, filesize($from));
                fwrite($createFile, $newcontent);
                fclose($createFile);
                // echo "Wait for 5 seconds";
                // setcookie("file", json_encode($casinoDetails), time() + 7400);
                // header("REFRESH: 5;profile/$username/profile.php");
                // echo "good";
            }
```

Comment: You can have ```HTML``` inside a ```.php``` file. But you cannot have ```PHP``` code inside a ```.html``` file. It won't be parsed.

Comment: I just need php output in an html file. I mean copy php output and then save it in a new html file.

Comment: @Innovin I know that php code doesn't work in html files. but i don't need to run php code inside html files. I just want  to copy php output data from a **casino-review .php** file to a new html file

Comment: You  save the ```php``` output data into a variable and copy it to a new html file using ```file_put_contents()```

Comment: @Innovin I don't know how to do that please help me give me some code or example i am so worried.

Comment: Email me via my profile if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: @Innovin sorry but i cannot email you. Can you help me here if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found my answer

```
ob_start();
include("$from");
file_put_contents($to, ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

Thanks @Innovin

Comment: Nice! Told ya you could do it with ```file_put_contents()```. Your code was just quite a bit confusing.